# Restrictions pin change

Tags: iphone

I have inherited an iphone as my work phone, the user previously set the restrictions PIN number and I have no idea what it could be and therefore cannot change and delete his apps
Any body got any ideas.

Comment: What iOS version and which iPhone are we talking about? Please add some details.

Comment: cant you just ask the coworker for the pin?

Answer (score 1):

You can restore your device to remove the restrictions passcode. This will delete the contents of the device, but you can restore a backup afterwards.

Connect the device to iTunes, choose your device and click Restore. This will erase and restore your device. Once this process is complete, you can set up the device as a new device or choose to restore from an iTunes or iCloud backup.